# MySQL group_concat problem

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Greetings,

I have a very tricky problem with the **group_concat** function and I'm thinking for some days with no success, how to solve it.

There are 3 tables:

```
tasks                    task_tag                 tag      
+---------+----------+   +---------+----------+   +---------+----------+
| task_id |   data   |   | task_id |  tag_id  |   | tag_id  |   name   |
+---------+----------+   +---------+----------+   +---------+----------+
|       1 | task 1   |   |    1    |    5     |   |    5    |   work   |
|       2 | task 2   |   |    1    |    7     |   |    6    |  school  |
|       3 | task 3   |   |    2    |    6     |   |    7    |   home   |
+---------+----------+   +---------+----------+   +---------+----------+
```

When all tasks need to be retrieved, with all tags that they are associated with as a result column, there is no problem with the following query:

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.data, GROUP_CONCAT(tg.name) AS tags
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN task_tag tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
LEFT JOIN tag tg ON tg.tag_id = tt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.task_id

result
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| task_id |  data     |   tags      |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|    1    |  task 1   |  work,home  |
|    2    |  task 2   |  school     |
|    3    |  task 3   |  NULL       |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

The problem is when I need to select the tasks from one EXACT tag, but I still need to preserve the tags column with all of the tasks' associated tags. I try with the following query, but since the result is limited by WHERE tag_id = 5, the group_concat function retrieves just the tag with id = 5, e.g. "work":

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.data, GROUP_CONCAT(tg.name) AS tags
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN task_tag tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
LEFT JOIN tag tg ON tg.tag_id = tt.tag_id
WHERE tg.tag_id = 5
GROUP BY t.task_id

result
+---------+-----------+-------------+   
| task_id |   data    |      tags   |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|    1    |  task 1   |      work   |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

The result that I'm trying to achieve is:

```
result
+---------+-----------+-------------+   
| task_id |  data     |     tags    |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|    1    |  task 1   |  work,home  |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions on how to resolve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by modifying your first query to include a where clause with a subquery:

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.data, GROUP_CONCAT(tg.name) AS tags
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN task_tag tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
LEFT JOIN tag tg ON tg.tag_id = tt.tag_id
WHERE t.task_id IN (SELECT task_id FROM task_tags WHERE tag_id=5)
GROUP BY t.task_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your query seems to be the fastest from the three answers with my test data, which is 200.000 tasks, 1000 tags, 10.000 task_tag and the tag I'm testing against has 1000 tasks connected with it. For sure it's not absolutely real data, but your query also is the most simple to do :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, I think this produces the sort of results you were imagining:

```
SELECT tasks.task_id, tasks.data, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.name) AS tags
FROM tag AS looking_for
JOIN task_tag AS first_tt ON first_tt.tag_id = looking_for.tag_id
JOIN tasks ON tasks.task_id = task_tag.task_id
JOIN task_tag AS second_tt ON second_tt.task_id = tasks.task_id
JOIN tag ON tag.tag_id = second_tt.tag_id
WHERE looking_for.tag_id = 5
GROUP BY tasks.task_id
```

It starts with the first tag you were looking for, works its way back to the task associated with it, and then JOINs on all the tags for that task.

Answer (score 1):

Use a HAVING instead of a WHERE, since a WHERE clause goes for every single row:

```
SELECT t.task_id, t.data, GROUP_CONCAT(tg.name) AS tags
FROM tasks t
LEFT JOIN task_tag tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
LEFT JOIN tag tg ON tg.tag_id = tt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.task_id
HAVING Count(IF(tg.tag_id = 5,1,NULL)) > 0
```